# Map List items with IEnumerable interface

Tags: c#, .net, linq

The `System.Collections.Generic.List` type implements `IEnumerable`, so I should be able to call `Select` or use a `from` expression, but doing so the compiler complains it is not supported.

I tried this in [dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/F4oCn5) (.NET 6):

```cs
var a = new List<string>();

// either 1)
var a2 = a.Select(s => s);

// either 2)
var a2 = from s in a select s;
```

For the `Select` method, I get:

```
'List<string>' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no accessible extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'List<string>' could be found
```

For the `from` expression, I get:

```
Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'List<string>'.  'Select' not found.
```

In my current case, I get (with .NET Core 6.0.200):

```
error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

With this code:

```
lines = lines.Select(line => {
    for (int i = 0; i < indent; i += 1) {
        if (!SourceCharacter.IsWhitespace(line[i])) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return FlexSubstring.Substring(line, i);
});
```

When I place an explicit conversion here, my library builds. But I'm not prepared to run the code now to make sure it converts successfuly. Thus I tried it in the playground above, and am wondering why compiling code like this in different environments produce different errors.

Comment: .Select(...) and 'from .. in ...' are placed in System.Linq, you should add that to the usings too.

Answer (score 0):

Working fine. There was just a typo in

```cs
var a = new List<string>();

// either 1)
var a2 = a.Select(s => s);
//        ^--- not a valid point? (Encoding? Maybe just my fault)
// either 2)
var a2 = from s in a select s;
```

And you have forgotten to include `using System.Linq`

[Working dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mPkpSw)

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;                   

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var a = new List<string> { "Test1", "Test2" };
        var a2 = a.Select(s => s);
        var a3 = from s in a select s;
        
        foreach(var i in a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `Select` is an extension method. In order for the C# compiler to pick up this method you must add a using statement.

```
using System.Linq;
```

With this, your code now compiles.